# Connect to vpn pptpd ubuntu vpn

Tags: windows

I configurated a VPN using PPTPD on Ubuntu 20.04. Here my files:

---

• /etc/pptpd.conf

```
option /etc/ppp/pptpd-options
logwtmp
localip 192.168.1.69
remoteip 192.168.1.30-39
```

---

• /etc/ppp/pptpd-options

```
name pptpd
refuse-pap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
require-mschap-v2
require-mppe-128
proxyarp
nodefaultroute
lock
nobsdcomp
noipx
mtu 1490
mru 1490
```

---

• /etc/ppp/options

```
lock
```

---

• /etc/ppp/chap-secrets

```
#username server password IPAddress
user pptpd password *
```

Using my Ubuntu client, I can connect successfully to VPN, but when I try using Windows client, it no connect. After 5 minutes trying connect, appear "We can't identify server".

How I can fix this?

Best regards